# Perfom python unit tests via a web interface

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is it possible to perform unittest tests via a web interface...and if so how?

**EDIT**: 
For now I want the results...for the tests I want them to be automated...possibly every time I make a change to the code.  Sorry I forgot to make this more clear

Comment: Do you want to run the tests from the web interface, view the results, or both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT:

This answer is outdated at this point:

- Use [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) instead of Hudson (same thing, new name).
- Use [django-jenkins](https://sites.google.com/site/kmmbvnr/home/django-jenkins-tutorial) instead of xmlrunner.py.

The link to django-jenkins goes to a nice tutorial on how to use Jenkins with Django.  I'll leave the text below since it still has some nice information.

---

As Bryan said, I'd use [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) to schedule, run, and collect the test results.  You can modify your tests to use [xmlrunner.py](https://pastebin.com/E4QHp21B) (written by Sebastian Rittau), which will output your test results into an JUnit compatible XML file for Hudson.

Here's an example of how the test code would use xmlrunner:

```
import unittest
import xmlrunner

class TheTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def testOne(self):
        self.assertEquals(1, 1)
    def testTwo(self):
        self.assertEquals(2, 2)
    def testThree(self):
        self.assertEquals(3, 4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TheTest)
    xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Once you install Hudson, you'll create a new project for the source repository you're testing.  You'll need to RTFM, but in a nutshell:

1. Under Source Code Management, you'll enter your repositories information and make it poll the repo periodically (I usually just do * * * * * so it checks every minute)
2. Add a command that actually runs the test script (like `python test.py`).
3. Check the Publish JUnit test result report.  If it has an error like `'TEST-*.xml' doesn't match anything` you can safely ignore it.  It'll look something like this:
   [image: JUnit Settings]
   <sub>(source: [snowpeaksoftware.com](http://www.snowpeaksoftware.com/stuff/hudson_config.png))</sub>

Once that's all done you'll be able to see test results for every time Hudson runs after check-in.  It'll look something like this:

[image: Hudson Unit Test Results]
<sub>(source: [snowpeaksoftware.com](http://www.snowpeaksoftware.com/stuff/unittest_results.png))</sub>

You also get more detailed pages like this page:

[image: Hudson Unit Test Detailed Results]
<sub>(source: [snowpeaksoftware.com](http://www.snowpeaksoftware.com/stuff/test_results_detailed1.png))</sub>

and this page:

[image: Hudson Unit Test Detailed Results]
<sub>(source: [snowpeaksoftware.com](http://www.snowpeaksoftware.com/stuff/test_results_detailed2.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) to schedule the tests to run whenever you check in code. Since Hudson is a web app, you can then see the results via the web (and/or publish them and/or email them to you or your team).