# Junit HTML report builder

Tags: python, html, junit, test-reporting

Consider the following [XML results of a JUnit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904997/perfom-python-unit-tests-via-a-web-interface):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<testsuite errors="0" failures="1" name="TheTest-20130618162859" 
           tests="3" time="0.000">
        <testcase classname="TheTest" name="testOne" time="0.000"/>
        <testcase classname="TheTest" name="testTwo" time="0.000"/>
        <testcase classname="TheTest" name="testThree" time="0.000">
                <failure message="3 != 4" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah.py", line 11, in testThree
    self.assertEquals(3, 4)
AssertionError: 3 != 4
]]>             </failure>
        </testcase>
        <system-out>
<![CDATA[]]>    </system-out>
        <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>    </system-err>
</testsuite>
```

How do I create a HTML report from these results?

**Addendum:**
Each execution of the test suite creates a new file:

```
TEST-TheTest-20130618162859.xml
TEST-TheTest-20130618163459.xml
TEST-TheTest-20130618163600.xml
```

I'd prefer a report builder that can view the history of each test.

Answer (score 1):

If you could use Ant then you would just use the JUnitReport task as detailed [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html)

If you are using Maven then use [Surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/)

Or if you want to run XSLT transform yourself [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/core/branches/ANT_14_BRANCH/src/etc/junit-frames.xsl) is the XSLT file used by ANT